# Any simple way to create link in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

Sometimes i need create a absolute link in a web site.

Like `http://example.com/xxxx/xxxx?foo=bar` not `/xxxx/xxxx?foo=bar`

Here has anyway to create a simple helper for express manually?

Just like:

```
app.locals.url = function ( pathTo, opts ) {
    // Somethings here.
}
```

I think they may need SSL check, host and route check or somethings.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the full URL :

```
var URL = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

Them You can redirect to this URL